# Can I specify PyPI server information such as username and password on the command line instead of using .pypirc?

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

My .pypirc file:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  internal

[pypi]
username:pypiusername
password:pypipasswd

[internal]
repository: http://10.11.12.13:8080
username: ning
password: xxxx
```

I want to write a script that upload packages but don't want to require a .pypirc file on the machine where it runs. I can specify repository with `-r`, but is there a way to specify `username` and `password` as well? Or Is there an option to pass a different file (e.g `--config-file ./my-pypyrc`)

Comment: you could try to prefix the repository url with `username:password@http://yourrepo:8000`

Answer (score 4):

I'm flabbergasted that setuptools has no secure way to do this on the command line, but you can use Twine (https://github.com/pypa/twine)

```
twine upload -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD dist/*
```